# How to use external CSS class using flutter_html?

Tags: html, css, flutter, dart, flutter-html

I'm using [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) to load a widget from HTML. I got the builder from an API that returns a HTML string with an external CSS class, roughly like this:

```
<p class="text-right">Supposed to be following text-right styles</p>
```

Suppose I have the styling for the `"text-right"` class, how can we load the style using `flutter_html`? In this case, I'm not using flutter WebView and I don't want to since the HTML only a small widget inside an existing scrolling page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using 3.0.0 and was able to do the following:

```
"p.text-right" : Style(
  textAlign: TextAlign.right
),
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add a tag list that is included in your HTML content and after adding this apply the style in the style parameter.

```
Container(
                child: Html(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  data: 'Your HTML content',
                  style: {
                    "body": Style(
                      margin: Margins.zero,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      fontSize: FontSize(17.0),
                      lineHeight: LineHeight(1.4),
                    ),
                    "p": Style(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight // for text right 
                    ),
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

You achieve this without giving a custom style

```
Html(data: """
     <p style="text-align: right">Text-Right</p>
     <p style="text-align: center">Text-center</p>
     <p style="text-align: left">Text-left</p>
    """,                  )
```

output:

[image]

Comment: thx for the answer, but I think you don't get my point. In this case, the class is inside the 'p' tag. I believe, even adding custom render won't work, since it can only translate the tag not the class inside it.

Comment: That's why we add a custom style in style like `"p": Style(alignment: Alignment.centerRight)`.

Comment: I get it, now the problem is, the class is dynamic, it's not statically "text-rigtht", do I have to parse it manually? And how to do so? Any reference?

Comment: Then you need need to modify your HTML string that was received from API. For this check my updated answer without giving a custom style section.